# Adding files for installer

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation

I can Add `.JPEG, .PNG, .SDF, .MDF` and etc.. but why I can't add `.Ink` extension for my Setup Project?

Comment: To what folder you want this shortcut to redirect?

Comment: I want the `.Ink` extension, in any folder.

Comment: Yes but pointing to what folder?

Comment: Because if you right click in one of your destination folder, you can `Create New Shortcut`

Comment: yes, right, my point is, I want to add the exist file(`.Ink` extension) in my Installer __not__ to create a `.Ink` Extension to my Installer. :)

Comment: So my question was, where is this `.Ink` pointing at? Because every Windows installation can be different, I don't think it's a good idea to have a static `.ink` file inside your setup, and probably the reason why Visual Studio doesn't let you do it!

Comment: again, in any folder or any point bro, can you give me a reference for that issue about `.ink` extension, why we can't add a `.ink`(Exist shortcut) to our installer(Setup Project)?

Comment: You definitely can create a shortcut but it is has to be relative to your file(s)/folder(s) installation. What file do you want to point at that is not part of your project? Because if you want to create a shortcut for a file from your project, just right click -> create shortcut on it, and move the `.ink` wherever you want! (I am trying to find a link about this)

Comment: Ok I can't find a link saying why but once again, in what circumstance do you have to copy/paste a shortcut in your setup process? It makes way more sense to dynamically create a shortcut that use the same than on your computer (what tells you that the user will have the same path for your target than you?).

Comment: let say is not or part of the project. i will just create a shortcut and add into a `Setup Project` not create a shortcut. i know how to create a shortcut, i just want to know what is the real reason, why we can't add a `.ink`extension to our Setup Project.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but i'am seeking ONLY about `.ink` extension, on why we can't add a .ink(Exist shortcut) to our installer(Setup Project)? :)

Comment: I understand what you want to do but I don't see a "real case" where it could apply and to me, it doesn't make sense to add a `.ink` file to your setup. Sorry if I'm wrong :)

Comment: i respect your opinion, its okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

.Ink is shortcut i think that's why you can't add it , i think you want to create a shortcut in the desktop for that you can try this

```
Imports IWshRuntimeLibrary

 Dim WshShell As WshShellClass = New WshShellClass
        Dim MyShortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut
        ' The shortcut will be created on the desktop
        Dim DesktopFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
        MyShortcut = CType(WshShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopFolder & "\MyShortcutName.lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)
        MyShortcut.TargetPath = Application.StartupPath & "\YourApp.exe" 'Specify target app full path
        MyShortcut.Save()
End Sub
```